# Xcode 5 can't open .m file

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I installed Xcode 5 a few hours ago. I opened my project with it. I have several .h and .m file in my project. I could view all of them except one of my .m file. When i clicked that .m file, the cursor became rainbow and nothing happened.

To be sure , i checked my project folder, go to the that .m file and click get info. I could see the preview of that file. Also i could open it in text editors.

I couldn't find the problem. Any advice is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Taha

---

I created a new project to check that .m file. And the result is positive. But still i can't open that .m file in my real project.

Comment: Did u try to add the .m files again?

Comment: Yes, i just deleted .m file and added again. However the result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird solution but works for me.

1) Delete .h and .m files.
2) Right click on xx.xcodeproj and click show package contents.
3) Delete project.xcworkspace.
4) Add .h and .m files again.

Comment: You probably don't want to *delete* the files, rather remove them. You should probably clarify this, so that data doesn't get accidentally removed.

Comment: I don't think I want to know why this works, but it did the trick for me.